# WooCommerce: Add class to notice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, notice

I want to add an extra class to my WooCommerce notice.

Here's my current code for printing the notice:

```
wc_print_notice( 'My message', 'success' );
```

I saw in the **[WooCommerce Docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_print_notice)**, that there is an option to add extra `$data` to the notice.

But something like this won't work (it adds only `data-class="extra"` to it):

```
wc_print_notice( 'My message', 'success', array('class' => 'extra') );
```

Is there an option to do this or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to add extra class within the function, nor is there a filter to use.

What you can do is overwrite the template, by copying to `yourtheme/woocommerce/notices/notice.php` (or `success.php`)

Answer (score 2):

I found an optional solution for my case. It would be possible to simply style the notice with the data attribute. Like this:

```
.woocommerce-message[data-class="extra"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```